# How to get Selenium test working properly?

Tags: python, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I tried to make test, but It fails. I'm not sure what that "#None" means. In tutorial everything worked. I'd be glad for help.

too_short_username_steps.feature

```
Feature: Username field
abc
Scenario: Too short Username
    Given user is on last.fm registration website
    When user fills in the username box with one character
    Then User can see Your username should be between 2 and 15 characters, begin with a letter and contain only letters, numbers,
```

too_short_username_steps.py

```
  from behave import given, when, then

    @given('user is on last.fm register site')
    def step_start_page(context):
        context.driver.get('https://www.last.fm/join')

    @when('user fills one character in username field')
    def step_set_username(context):
        context.driver.find_element_by_id('id_userName').send_keys('a')

    @then('User can see ')
    def step_valid_warning(context):
        assert context.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#mantle_skin > div.container.page-content > div > div > form > div.form-group.form-group--userName.js-form-group.has-error > div > div.js-form-group-error.form-group-error > div > p")
```

When i run "behave":

```
Feature: Username field # features/too_short_username.feature:1
  dasdasd
  Scenario: Too short Username                                                                                                                # features/too_short_username.feature:3
    Given user is on last.fm registration website                                                                                             # None
    When user fills in the username box with one character                                                                                    # None
    Then User can see Your username should be between 2 and 15 characters, begin with a letter and contain only letters, numbers, '_' or '-'. # None


Failing scenarios:
  features/too_short_username.feature:3  Too short Username

0 features passed, 1 failed, 0 skipped
0 scenarios passed, 1 failed, 0 skipped
0 steps passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped, 3 undefined
Took 0m0.000s

You can implement step definitions for undefined steps with these snippets:

@given(u'user is on last.fm registration website')
def step_impl(context):
    raise NotImplementedError(u'STEP: Given user is on last.fm registration website')


@when(u'user fills in the username box with one character')
def step_impl(context):
    raise NotImplementedError(u'STEP: When user fills in the username box with one character')


@then(u'User can see Your username should be between 2 and 15 characters, begin with a letter and contain only letters, numbers, \'_\' or \'-\'.')
def step_impl(context):
    raise NotImplementedError(u'STEP: Then User can see Your username should be between 2 and 15 characters, begin with a letter and contain only letters, numbers, \'_\' or \'-\'.')
```

Comment: Where is **"#None"** occurring?

Comment: Your steps must have the same sentence from the bdd script. You have '    @then('User can see ')' but your sentence inside the bdd is:     Then User can see Your username should be between 2 and 15 characters, begin with a letter and contain only letters, numbers. Thus, the framework cannot recognize your integration between technical and bdd steps.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence for each step in scenario  must be the same written as in steps definition in file too_short_username_steps.py then performed steps from scenario will be mapped to definitions. As example "user is on last.fm registration website" is not eqal to "user is on last.fm register site" that's why it failed, step couldn't be found. It should looks like below:

```
from behave import given, when, then

@given('user is on last.fm registration website')
def step_start_page(context):
    context.driver.get('https://www.last.fm/join')

@when('user fills in the username box with one character')
def step_set_username(context):
    context.driver.find_element_by_id('id_userName').send_keys('a')

@then('User can see Your username should be between 2 and 15 characters, begin with a letter and contain only letters, numbers,')
def step_valid_warning(context):
    assert context.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#mantle_skin > div.container.page-content > div > div > form > div.form-group.form-group--userName.js-form-group.has-error > div > div.js-form-group-error.form-group-error > div > p")
```